# Numpy computes strange eigeinvectors

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I was computing the eigenvectors of a matrix using numpy and I was getting some weird results. Then I decided to use Matlab and everything was fine.

```
L = np.array(([2,-1,-1],[-1,2,-1],[-1,-1,2]))
Lam,U = np.linalg.eig(L) #compute eigenvalues and vectors
#sort by ascending eigenvalues
I = [i[0] for i in sorted(zip(xrange(len(Lam)),Lam),key=lambda x: x[1])] 
Lam = Lam[I]
U = U[:,I]
print U.dot(U.T)

>> [[ 1.09 -0.24  0.15]
   [-0.24  1.15  0.09]
   [ 0.15  0.09  0.76]]
```

The result was weird because I was expecting `U.dot(U.T) = I`. In matlab:

```
L = [2,-1,-1;-1,2,-1;-1,-1,2]
[V,D] = eig(L)
V*V'
ans =
    1.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    1.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
```

By the way U:

```
[[-0.58  0.82  0.29]
 [-0.58 -0.41 -0.81]
 [-0.58 -0.41  0.51]]
```

and V:

```
0.5774    0.7634    0.2895
0.5774   -0.6325    0.5164
0.5774   -0.1310   -0.8059
```

What's going on?

Comment: Not sure yet, what is going on but just two hints: `[i[0] for i in sorted(zip(xrange(len(Lam)),Lam),key=lambda x: x[1])]` is basically `np.argsort(Lam)` and `zip(xrange(len(Lam)),Lam)` is `enumerate(Lam)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is true that there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of a symmetrical matrix, there is no guarantee that Numpy will return that basis.  It will return *any* basis of eigenvectors, and there is nothing wrong about this approach.

The matrix you are looking at has two eigenspaces: A two-dimensional one for the eigenvalue 3, and the one-dimensional kernel.  For the kernel, the eigenvector is determined up to a constant factor.  For the two-dimensional space, however, you have some freedom to choose a basis, and there is no guarantee that it is orthonormal.

To get an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix, you can use [`numpy.linalg.eigh()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html).

Comment: is there a Gram–Schmidt orthonormalisation method implemented?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Not in Numpy, as far as I'm aware, but there is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orth.html.  However, you would generally simply use a singular-value decomposition if you want an orthonormal eigenvector basis.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that your matrix is NOT reversible

```
np.linalg.det(L) # Return 0
Lam # Return [3, 3, 0]
```

So:

```
det(L * U) = det(L) * det(U) = 0 != det(I) = 1
```